# What do you use for setting loop points and crossfading? Do you know of an audio editor that lets you select the crossfade curve?

Tags: sound-editing, looping

I'm trying to loop a sample so that I can sustain it on a sampler. I usually use Image-Line's Edison's "tune loop" tool but it doesn't always give me what I want. I was using the sampler in phaseplant which has looping functionality built in, and gives a much smoother crossfade in my opinion. I think it has to do with the kind of crossfade curve used.

Unfortunately Phaseplant doesn't let you export those loop points. So I was looking for an audio editor that allows the user to specify the crossfade curve. Surprisingly I struggled to find any program that had loop/crossfade functionality at all... maybe I'm not googling correctly.

I did find this, which has the functionality I'm looking for, but it only goes up to 24-bit wavs: https://www.kvraudio.com/product/endless-wav-by-bjoern-bojahr

Just wanted to know what other sound designers use, and if there are other options.